# Android Navigation Architecture Component - Nested NavHostFragment

Tags: android, navigation

- Already Main `NavHostFragment` integrate with `BottomNavigationMenu` which is working fine, where I will add another `NavHostFragment` to update the fragment within current Fragment.
- For Example A - `NavHostFragment` which has `BottomNaviagationMenu` with four items, when select 2nd items it shows one fragment which is called as B. In this B Fragment has two buttons named as "First","Second" and another `NavHostFragment`.
- "First" button is clicked update the corresponding fragment in same screen below the buttons `NavHostFramgent`.

This is scenario, how can I achieve??

Comment: attach visual images for better understanding.

Comment: look for any blog or post anything that you have tried so far.